# Realm - where last version of library?

Tags: android, realm

I try add Reqlm to android project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}
```

But where I can see last version library(!!!not plugin version!!!)???

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.72.0'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.72.0'
```

I found 0.72.0 but where last version?

Comment: The Gradle plugin *is* the latest version. That's how it's been since 0.88.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://bintray.com/realm/maven/realm-android) information latest version is 0.87.5. You can refer to [bintray.com](https://bintray.com/) to get updates for gradle packages.